# How do I find the minimum or maximum of a vector valued (defined) function (with sine and cosine) using differentiation?

Tags: functions, derivatives, trigonometry, optimization, vectors

For example this one, how do I find the answer for when $dy/dx$ equals $0$.
Image: see link below, it is the equation of the original function

Normally by using differentiation and funding the x value for when y equals 0 would give all minimums and maximums, however, with vector parameter i and j involves, I do not think high school algebra is going to work.

If it helps, the graph of it is below in the link.
https://www.geogebra.org/m/zk2a33w4

PS. About motivation, I need it for a school work and the first draft is due in September. About who am I, I am a high school student. And about reference, these equations are formed from data collected in an experiment. And about definition, these are simple maths terms, I do not think there is anything that needs a definition.

Comment: I see no image.

Comment: It is in the link, look on the left side, the equation of function.

Comment: The link you provided isn't working properly.  I suggest you write the function explicitly in the question using Mathjax.